# One to Many doesn't differentiate within groups in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, one-to-many

I am trying to build an app in which users can create groups and create individual Posts within those groups which, at the end, will lead to the specific PostDetailsView. So: Post in Group A is different to Post in Group B.
I tried to implement by following a tutorial with One To Many. however, after following the steps carefully, the groups still display the same content.

Structure: Groups -> post -> ...

This is an exhibit from my Group+CoreDataProperties:

```
extension Groups {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Groups> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Groups>(entityName: "Groups")
}

@NSManaged public var groupThumbnail: Data?
@NSManaged public var groupTitle: String?
@NSManaged public var id: UUID?
@NSManaged public var posts: Set<Posts>?

public var postsBind: [Posts] {
    let setPosts = posts
    return setPosts!.sorted {
        $0.id > $1.id
    }
}
```

This is my SetUp for HomeView:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(entity: Groups.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Groups.groupTitle, ascending:true),
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Groups.groupThumbnail, ascending:true),
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Groups.id, ascending:true),
])

var groups: FetchedResults<Groups>
```

This is an exhibit of how I present groups on HomeView:

```
LazyVStack (spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(groups, id:\.self) { Group in
                        NavigationLink(destination: GroupView()) {
                            ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                                
                                Image(uiImage: (UIImage(data: Group.groupThumbnail ?? self.image) ?? UIImage(named: "defaultGroupThumbnail"))!)
                                    .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
                                    .cornerRadius(22)
                                
                                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                    
                                    Text("\(Group.groupTitle ?? "Untitled")")
                                        .font(.title)
                                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    
                                    Text("Consists of 5 Posts")
                                }
                                .padding([.leading, .bottom], 18.0)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            }
                        }
```

This is an exhibit of the Setup of the CreateGroupView:

```
@State var image : Data = .init(count: 0)

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

@FetchRequest(entity: Groups.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Groups.groupTitle, ascending:true),
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Groups.groupThumbnail, ascending:true)
])

var groups: FetchedResults<Groups>
```

This is an exhibit of how I pass in the details when creating Groups on external View:

```
.toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Done"){
                        //addGroup()
                        let send = Groups(context: self.viewContext)
                        send.groupTitle = self.groupName
                        send.groupThumbnail = self.image
                        send.id = UUID()
                    
                    try? self.viewContext.save()
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    self.groupName = ""
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
```

This is an exhibit of the Setup of the CreatePostView:

```
 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

@FetchRequest(entity: Posts.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Posts.postsTitle, ascending:true),
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Posts.postsThumbnail, ascending:true)
])

var post: FetchedResults<Posts>
```

Exhibit of what I pass in when creating Posts:

```
.toolbar {
                ToolbarItem (placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                Button("Done"){
                    let send = Posts(context: self.viewContext)
                    send.postsTitle = self.postsName
                    send.postsThumbnail = self.image
                    send.id = UUID()
                
                try? self.viewContext.save()
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                self.postsName = ""
            }
            }
            ToolbarItem (placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Button("Cancel") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
```

This is the Setup of the PostsView, where all Posts are presented:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

@FetchRequest(entity: Posts.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Posts.postsTitle, ascending:true),
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Posts.postsThumbnail, ascending:true),
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Posts.id, ascending:true)
])

private var posts: FetchedResults<Posts>
```

This is an exhibit of how I present Posts:

```
LazyVGrid( columns: twoColumnGrid, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach((post), id: \.self) { Post in
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                        ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                self.isPresentingPostDetailView.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                Image(uiImage: (UIImage(data: Post.postThumbnail ?? self.image) ?? UIImage(named: "defaultGroupThumbnail"))!)
                                    .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(width: 165, height: 165)
                                    .cornerRadius(22)
                                    .scaledToFill()
                            })
```

I hope this is not too long. I don't exactly know where the problem is and what you might need. I have been trying for a few hours now. But nothing seems to solve my problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Kind Regards

Comment: A lot of code but I don’t see that you assign a group when you are creating a new Posts. Btw, you should try to name your entities in singular form, Group and Post

Comment: This is a tough ask when dealing with Core Data, but his needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can cut a lot of stuff out of your views, like the thumbnails, etc, and just stick to displaying `GroupTitle` and `PostTitle`. And make sure you gives us the entire class or struct, not pieces. Lastly, post screenshots of your Core Data model, especially with the relationship set up.